# django boolean default not respected when not specifically excluded in form

Tags: python, django

I'm using django 1.5.

In my model definition, I have a boolean field with `default=True` defined. However, when a record is saved using my `modelForm`, the value is not saved as `True` with the record; it is saved as `False`.

forms.py

```
class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    hours = forms.DecimalField(required=False,
        max_digits=5,
        decimal_places=2,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'3.5'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Example
        exclude = ('fk')
```

models.py

```
class Example(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    fk = models.ForeignKey(FK)

    hours = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

They way this is set up to me it would seem that since `active` is not provided by the form that there is no value supplied when validating the record, therefore it should default to the `default` value set in the `model`. That is NOT the case. It defaults to `False`. However, I notice that if I explicitly add it to `exclude`d fields, then the default does stay at `True`. I.e. if I change this line `exclude = ('fk')` to `exclude = ('fk','active')` and change nothing else, the validation works as I would expect.

Is this the correct behavior? **My assumption that if a model field is not specified in the form it will use the `default` value defined in the model is wrong?** This seems counterintuitive to me... just want to make sure I'm not missing anything.

Comment: Why do you say that `active` is not provided by the form? The only thing you exclude is `fk`, so there *is* an `active` field.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Perhaps my misunderstanding is here then. I didn't define an `active` field in my form, and even if one is implicitly created, I didn't supply an input in my template. So, considering my form is validated with values from my `POST` request, where would the `active` data come from?

Comment: Yes, one is implicitly created unless you exclude it; the other thing you're missing is that browsers don't send data for unchecked checkboxes, so Django must necessarily interpret "no data" for a BooleanField as False. If you want to use the model default, exclude the field completely as you do with `fk`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks for that.